# What's the difference between abstract algebra and group theory tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

When should a question tagged with group theory (and is just on groups) be also tagged with abstract algebra?

The main reason I'm asking, is because I'm seeing a user make several edits to questions by simply adding abstract algebra to questions already tagged with group theory. Should this be encouraged? I've rejected most of his edits (under the too minor option), but I was informed that it has been approved in some cases.

E.g.

[image]

Comment: My question: How can the addition of a single tag be even remotely described as "improved formatting"?

Comment: An analogous example is the [tag:calculus] tag and the [tag:integration] tag.  When should an [tag:integration] problem be tagged [tag:calculus]? (Rhetorical question... `:)`)

Comment: @ArthurFischer You'd be amazed what is possible when words are used without regard to their meanings :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my philosophy some of the "umbrella tags" are useful for the less-frequent tags. In particular, this would be an edit I'd reject (but not reverse).

The [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) is relevant for every question which is about group theory, ring theory, modules, fields, Galois theory, and more and more. It's a huge topic, and it clearly covers a lot more than [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory).

Some of the subjects have well-represented tags here, like the group theory tag with over 6,000 questions and nearly 400 followers. However tags like [rngs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rngs) have vastly less exposure to the main page. So it is useful to have an umbrella tag like [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) or [ring-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-theory) available with it.

In conclusion, my argument is that [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) is usually for increasing the exposure of a question whose other tags are indeed relevant to abstract algebra, but have less followers; and rarely for questions about "general" abstract algebra. Of course [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory) isn't such tag.